# Como implementar varios contadores en retroceso en C# utilizando el menor código posible?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vb.net, windows-forms, .net

Tengo el siguiente código que uso para la implementación de un sistema de gestión para una sala de juegos con consolas de videojuegos y simuladores, la cosa es que tengo este método para generar temporizadores para sesiones de juego, pero no quiero tener que repetir el código unas 24 veces mas para cada una de las maquinas, debe existir una forma mas eficiente de hacerlo, por ahora solo he logrado hacer funcionar un contador en retroceso, enviándole las variables de tiempo Segundos, Minutos y Horas a través de controles combo box, posteriormente planeo hacerlo mediante base de datos para crear perfiles con saldo por clientes, pero hasta no resolver el problema de eficiencia en código de mis contadores no me atrevo a continuar, sin mas que decir este es mi código:

**Metodo para el contador**

```
private void CuentaRegresiva(Label Contador, Timer Timer, GroupBox Consola)
    {

        seg = seg - 1;
        string minutos = min.ToString();
        string horas = hor.ToString();
        string segundos = seg.ToString();
        if (seg < 10) { segundos = "0" + segundos.ToString(); }
        if (min < 10) { minutos = "0" + minutos.ToString(); }
        if (hor < 10) { horas = "0" + horas.ToString(); }


        if (seg == 0 && min > 0)
        {
            min = min - 1;
            seg = 59;
        }
        if (min == 0 && hor > 0 && seg > 0)
        {
            seg = 59;
            hor = hor - 1;
            min = 59;
        }
        if (hor > 0 && min == 0)
        {
            hor = hor - 1;
            min = 59;
            seg = 59;
        }
        if (hor == 0 && min == 0 && seg == 0)
        {
            Notificaciones(Consola);
            Timer.Stop();
            reproducirSonido();

        }

        Contador.Text = hor + ":" + min + ":" + seg;
    }
```

**Codigo de el boton para agregar los tiempos al timer**

```
 private void BtnSesionCliente_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CmbConsola.Text == "Playstation 5-1")
        {
            if (Temp_PS5_1.Text == "00:00:00")
            {
                hor_p5_1 = Convert.ToInt32(CmbHoras.Text);
                min_p5_1 = Convert.ToInt32(CmbMinutos.Text);
                hor = hor_p5_1;
                min = min_p5_1;
                seg = seg_p5_1;
                Temp_PS5_1.Text = hor_p5_1 + ":" + min_p5_1 + ":" + seg_p5_1;
                MessageBox.Show("Hora " + hor_p5_1 + " Min " + min_p5_1 + " Min " + seg_p5_1);
            }
            else MessageBox.Show("Consola en uso, favor seleccionar otra disponible");
        }
        if (CmbConsola.Text == "Playstation 5-2")
        {
            if (Temp_PS5_2.Text == "00:00:00")
            {
                hor_p5_2 = Convert.ToInt32(CmbHoras.Text);
                min_p5_2 = Convert.ToInt32(CmbMinutos.Text);
                hor = hor_p5_2;
                min = min_p5_2;
                seg = seg_p5_2;
                Temp_PS5_2.Text = hor_p5_1 + ":" + min_p5_1 + ":" + seg_p5_1;
                MessageBox.Show("Hora " + hor_p5_1 + " Min " + min_p5_1 + " Min " + seg_p5_1);
            }
            else MessageBox.Show("Consola en uso, favor seleccionar otra disponible");
        }
    }
```

**Codigo para iniciar o terminar contadores de cada consola**

```
private void BtnIniciarP5_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimerPS5_1.Start();
    }
    private void BtnPausarP5_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimerPS5_1.Stop();
    }
    private void BtnIniciarP5_2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimerPS5_2.Start();
    }
    private void BtnPausarP5_2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimerPS5_2.Stop();
    }
```

**Codigo del Tick de cada timer**

```
private void TimerPS5_2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CuentaRegresiva(Temp_PS5_2, TimerPS5_2, GbPS5_2);
}
private void Timer_PS5_1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CuentaRegresiva(Temp_PS5_1, TimerPS5_1, GbPS5_1);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu estilo de programación se asemeja mucho a lo que se hacía antiguamente en vb6. C# es un lenguaje orientado a objetos, además provee características de para ligar la interfaz gráfica con esos objeto (Binding), la programación moderna ha avanzado justamente en lo que tu buscas, que es evitar el código repetitivo, que para mí es la diferencia entre programar y escribir un listado de instrucciones.

Por ejemplo puedes crear una Clase `Consola` donde tengas toda la lógica

```
public class Consola : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    private System.Timers.Timer timer;
    private TimeSpan Transcurso = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);


    public bool isFinish { get; set; } = false;
    public string Tiempo {
        get => string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", Transcurso.TotalHours, Transcurso.Minutes, Transcurso.Seconds);
    }

    public Consola(string Name)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
        timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
        AsignarTime(0, 0,3);
    }

    public void AsignarTime(int hora, int min, int seg = 0)
    {
        isFinish = false;
        Transcurso = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(hora * 3600 + min * 60 + seg);
    }

    public void Start() => timer.Start();
    public void Stop() => timer.Stop();
    public bool enUso() => timer.Enabled;

    private void Timer_Elapsed(object? sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Transcurso = Transcurso.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(-1));
        OnPropertyChanged("Tiempo"); //Avisamos que la propiedad Tiempo ha cambiado
        if (Transcurso.TotalSeconds <= 0)
        {
            isFinish = true;
            OnPropertyChanged("isFinish");
            //Notificaciones(Consola);
            Stop();
            //reproducirSonido();
        }
    }


    //Implementación de la Interfaz INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));


}
```

El código anterior implementa la Interfaz `INotifyPropertyChanged` con la cual se da aviso a la interfaz gráfica que hay alguna propiedad que ha cambiado, esto la actualizará automáticamente.

También te muestro otra forma de generar la cuenta regresiva. Y por último implemento algunas funcionalidades del `timer` como `Start` y `Stop`.

La idea general es tener una clase que implemente toda lógica de un objeto, luego creas la cantidad de objetos que tu necesites, sin la necesidad de repetir esa lógica.

Obviamente tu deberás agregar más propiedades y funciones para adecuarlo a tus necesidades.

Por último te dejo un ejemplo de un Form implementando esta clase, para eso he puesto un DataGridView llamado `dataGridView1`

```js
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //Lista de consolas
    public BindingList<Consola> consolaList = new BindingList<Consola>();
        
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //asignamos consolas a la lista
        consolaList.Add(new Consola("consola 1"));
        consolaList.Add(new Consola("consola 2"));

        //Binding de la lista al datagridview
        dataGridView1.DataSource = consolaList;

        //añadimos botones para ejecutar acciones
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(CreateButton("Iniciar"));
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(CreateButton("Parar"));
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(CreateButton("Asignar"));

        dataGridView1.CellContentClick += DataGridView1_CellContentClick1;
        dataGridView1.RowPostPaint += DataGridView1_RowPostPaint; ;
    }

    //Para cambiar el color de una fila cuando el tiempo haya terminado
    private void DataGridView1_RowPostPaint(object? sender, DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e)
    {
        var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender!;
        var consola = senderGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem as Consola;
        if ( consola is null)
            return;

        DataGridViewCellStyle style = senderGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle;
        if (consola.isFinish)
        {
            style.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            style.BackColor = Color.White;
        }

    }

    //Función que crea un botón en la grilla
    private DataGridViewButtonColumn CreateButton(string nombre)
    {
        DataGridViewButtonColumn button = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();

        button.Name = nombre;
        button.HeaderText = nombre;
        button.Text = nombre;
        button.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
        return button;
    }

    //detección de todos los botones
    private void DataGridView1_CellContentClick1(object? sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender!;
        var consola = senderGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem as Consola;
        var button = senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] as DataGridViewButtonColumn;
        if (button is null || consola is null)
            return;
        Execute(consola,button.Name);
            
    }

    private void Execute(Consola consola, string accion) 
    {
        if (accion == "Iniciar") consola.Start();
        else if (accion == "Parar") consola.Start();
        else if (accion == "Asignar") AbrirAsignacion(consola);

    }

    private void AbrirAsignacion(Consola consola)
    {
        if (!consola.enUso())
        {
            //Esto abre un otro form como ventana emergente, aquí podrías incluir un formulario para asignar el tiempo a cada consola
            //se pasa consola por parametro, para que dentro del form2 puedas acceder a las propiedades y funciones como por ejemplo AsignarTime
            var f = new Form2(consola);
            f.ShowDialog();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Consola en uso, favor seleccionar otra disponible");
        }
               
    }
}
```

*Nota: Mi idea no es entregar un código completo y funcional, seguramente hay varias cosas que tendrás que cambiar, pero creo que puede entregarte una idea de cómo empezar tu proyecto.*

Comment: Hola acabo de leer tu comentario, la verdad esta muy bien detallado el codigo ejemplo que planeaste, aunque yo pensaba colocar todas las consolas en recuadros individuales con Groupbox, creo que un DTGView caeria mejor para lo que intento, apenas lo termine te muestro el resultado!, un abrazo.

Comment: tengo un par de preguntas para ti sera que puedo contactarte via correo o discord?

Comment: @Ganinox Me alegro te haya ayudado, no tengo discord y me correo no lo doy.  Si tus preguntas son puntuales puedes dejármelas aquí en los comentarios o generar otra pregunta.  Ahora si son amplias, puedes subir tu código a Github, pones algún txt con las consultas y yo no tengo problema en revisar el código (mientras no sean un millón de líneas). Saludos

Comment: Es que quiero  asignar los tiempos desde un recuadro en el mismo formulario utilizando un cmb con las horas y otro con los minutos, pero no logro dar con la idea, debo usar el metodo Asignarconsola(), pero luego que? como le mando los parametros de tiempo a esa consola especifica? como le envio los parametros y que me actualice el DTGView?

Comment: @Ganinox con "cmb" supongo que te refieres a un combobox.  No es tan corta la explicación como para poder darla en un comentario, así que te recomiendo que generes otra pregunta sobre este tema en específico, algo de como:  "como agregar un combobox a un dataGridView haciendo binding a una propiedad", además si gustas cuando la hagas me avisas acá mismo para poder responderla.